# Error + JSON + <select> + <option>

Tags: json, html-select

I'm getting a very strange error after I upgraded to Angular 6.0.9. My template has a select, where there is an opnion with a value of "" and an "Select an Option" label, and the other options are generated by a list that comes from the bank.

So when I need to clear the form I call the formBuilder again. However, when I clean the form, a request occurs to api and consequently a json error, warning that it can not serialize a null value.

During the reset of the form I do not call any method that triggers the API, so I'm not sure what to do.

It is worth mentioning that the application still works, but it presents the user with an error message, since I have an interceptor that receives all errors and prints in a snack bar...

Template:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="selectTipoDocumento" formControlName="tipoDocumento" [compareWith]="equals"
          [class.is-valid]="this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].valid &&
           (this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].dirty)"
          [class.is-invalid]="!this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].valid &&
           (this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].dirty)">
            <option value="">Selecione um tipo</option>
            <option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposDocumento" [ngValue]="tipo">{{tipo?.nome}}</option>
          </select>
```

Component:

```
export class DocumentoDetalheComponent implements OnInit {
  docForm: FormGroup;
  tiposDocumento: TipoDocumento[];
  documento: Documento = new Documento();

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private tipoDocumentoService: TipoDocumentoService,
    private documentoService: DocumentoService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const idRota: string = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];

    this.createFormGroup();

    this.tipoDocumentoService.findAll().subscribe(
      obj => {
        this.tiposDocumento = obj;
      },
      error => { }
    ).unsubscribe;

    if (idRota != null){
    this.documentoService.findById(idRota).subscribe(
      obj => {
        this.documento = obj;

        this.docForm.setValue({
          tipoDocumento: this.documento.tipoDocumento,
          resumo: this.documento.resumo,
          observacao: this.documento.observacao
        });
      },
      error => { }
    );}
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let docTemp: Documento = this.docForm.value;
    this.documento.tipoDocumento = docTemp.tipoDocumento;
    this.documento.resumo = docTemp.resumo;
    this.documento.observacao = docTemp.observacao;


    if (this.documento.id == null) {
      this.save(this.documento);
    } else {
      this.update(this.documento);
    }
  }

  save(documento: Documento) {
    this.documentoService
      .insert(documento)
      .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }

  update(documento: Documento) {
    this.documentoService.update(documento).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }

  createFormGroup() {
    this.docForm = this.fb.group({
      tipoDocumento: ["", [Validators.required]],
      resumo: ["",[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(60)]],
      observacao: ["", [Validators.maxLength(500)]]
    });
  }

  limparForm() {
    this.createFormGroup();
  }
  equals(tp1: TipoDocumento, tp2: TipoDocumento) {
    return tp1.id === tp2.id
  }
  voltar() {}
}
```

API error:

```
2018-07-16 10:05:43.186  WARN 4996 --- [ tomcat-http--5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `br.mp.mpce.sge.domain.TipoDocumento` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (''); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `br.mp.mpce.sge.domain.TipoDocumento` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 579] (through reference chain: br.mp.mpce.sge.domain.Documento["tipoDocumento"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was in my formGroup, where I was using ngSubmit, so all buttons in my form were submitting API requests. So, the solution was to remove ngSubmir from the form, as well as manually set, in the event (click), the necessary methods.

```
<form [formGroup]="docForm" novalidate>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="documento?.id != null">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="setor">Nº Protocolo: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{documento?.codigo}}/{{documento?.ano}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="documento?.id != null">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="setor">Setor cadastro: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{documento?.setorCadastro?.nome}}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="selectTipoDocumento">Tipo de Documento: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <select class="form-control" id="selectTipoDocumento" formControlName="tipoDocumento" [compareWith]="equals"
          [class.is-valid]="this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].valid &&
           (this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].dirty)"
          [class.is-invalid]="!this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].valid &&
           (this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].dirty)">
            <option value="">Selecione um tipo</option>
            <option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposDocumento" [ngValue]="tipo">{{tipo?.nome}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 invalid-feedback d-block"
        *ngIf="!this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].valid && (this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['tipoDocumento'].dirty)">
          Tipo dodocumento é obrigatório
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="inputResumo">Resumo: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputResumo" formControlName="resumo" placeholder="Resumo do documento" maxlength="60"
            autocomplete="off"
            [class.is-valid]="this.docForm.controls['resumo'].valid && (this.docForm.controls['resumo'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['resumo'].dirty)"
            [class.is-invalid]="!this.docForm.controls['resumo'].valid && (this.docForm.controls['resumo'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['resumo'].dirty)">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 invalid-feedback d-block"
        *ngIf="!this.docForm.controls['resumo'].valid && (this.docForm.controls['resumo'].touched ||  this.docForm.controls['resumo'].dirty)">
          Resumo é obrigatório (5 a 60 caracteres)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="inputObservacao">Observação: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="inputObservacao" formControlName="observacao" rows="5">
      </textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="limparForm()">Limpar</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"[disabled]="!docForm.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">Salvar</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [routerLink]="['/']">Voltar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```